# How can I display a home-made magnifying glass image to the right of this DuckDuckGo search box?

Tags: html, css

I would like to display my own magnifying glass image to the right of a DuckDuckGo search box. The search itself is working, but the image is displayed below the box. How can I make it display to the right of it? My code is as follows:

```css
form input[type="text"] {
  height: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: top;
  maxlength="255";
}
```

```html
<form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
  <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a"/>
  <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder="&nbsp;..."/>
</form>
<img src="images/image.gif" height="20" width="20">
```

Comment: `#search { display: inline; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the search box and the image into a div with `display: inline-block;`

```
<form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
  <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a"/>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder="&nbsp;..."/>
    <img src="images/image.gif" height="20" width="20">
  </div>
</form>
```